# How Can I Throw an Error Within Asp.Net Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using a custom middleware to check for the tenant in the header of every request like so:

```
public TenantInfoMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    _next = next;
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    TenantInfoService tenantInfoService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TenantInfoService>();

    // Get tenant from request header
    var tenantName = context.Request.Headers["Tenant"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantName))
        tenantInfoService.SetTenant(tenantName);
    else
        tenantInfoService.SetTenant(null); // Throw 401 error here

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    await _next(context);
}
```

In the above code I would like to throw a 401 error within the pipeline. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: When you say "throw a 401 error within the pipeline", do you mean _return_ a 401: Unauthorised to the client?

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Sorry for that but StackOverflow did not let me phrase my question like that. @JohnH

Comment: I basically want to interrupt the pipeline and return a 401 instead of continuing with the next middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your comments for clarifying what you want to do. Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    TenantInfoService tenantInfoService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TenantInfoService>();

    // Get tenant from request header
    var tenantName = context.Request.Headers["Tenant"];

    // Check for tenant
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantName))
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return;
    }
    
    tenantInfoService.SetTenant(tenantName);

    await _next(context);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!
I guess, I can do `context.Response.Body = "foo"` to pass a message along with the status code?

Comment: Also, I edited my question and your answer because I still had a token snippet in there by accident.

Comment: @TomelSafadi You can use `context.Response.Body.WriteAsync` to modify the body, yeah.